# Datepicker values only change when changing date

Tags: xcode, datepicker

Is it possible to have datepicker land on todays date when the app starts?

currently my app shows no values on start up and only when I start changing the date in my datepicker then values start appearing. datepicker outputs values to labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which programming language do you use?

This code is for swift3 ;

You should write it in **viewDidLoad()**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        yourTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: (NSDate() as Date))
```

Comment: i am using swift 3. currently my code is sitting in the IBoutlet action property